# Elementor "saved templates page" lists letters type underneath each other

Tags: wordpress, elementor

After importing a templatekit through the envato elements plugin, the listed templates' letters (type) are underneath each other on elementors saved templates page. I searched the web trying to find a solution, but could not find one. I have uploaded a screenshot to illustrate the problem. Does anybody know a fix?

If more information is necessary, I'll be glad to provide it.

Thank you!

Screenshot link: https://ibb.co/hCKhs06

Searched Google, stack overflow...